# Calculating month-to-month sales variance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to calculate the month to month variance in sales over the past 3 years.  I am a little stuck on how to get the historical month's actual joined to the historical month's + 1 month actual.  When the month is December, it does not display in the result set, causing the next month of January not to display.

```
with _t1 as (
SELECT
Year(Invoicedate) as [Year]
,Month(Invoicedate) as [Month]
,Sum([TaxableSalesAmt]+[NonTaxableSalesAmt]+[FreightAmt]+[SalesTaxAmt]) as Revenue
FROM [InvoiceHistory]
where year(invoicedate) >= '2015'
group by Year(Invoicedate) ,Month(Invoicedate)
)
,_t2 as (
SELECT 
Year(Invoicedate) as [Year]
,Month(Invoicedate) as [Month]
,Sum([TaxableSalesAmt]+[NonTaxableSalesAmt]+[FreightAmt]+[SalesTaxAmt]) as Revenue
FROM [MAS_RDP].[dbo].[AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader]
where year(invoicedate) >= '2015'
group by Year(Invoicedate) ,Month(Invoicedate)
)

Select _t1.year
,_t1.Month
,_t1.Revenue
,_t2.year
,_t2.month
,_t2.Revenue
,_t2.Revenue-_t1.Revenue as GrowthActual
,(_t2.Revenue-_t1.Revenue)/_t2.Revenue*100 as GrowthPercent
from _t1
inner join _t2 on _t1.year = _t2.year and _t1.month = _t2.month-1
order by _t1.year, _t1.month
```

Comment: Use a CASE statement to handle December/January or use the DATEDIFF function (the later I recommend).

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a definition of "variance".  The technical definition doesn't really apply to two data points.

Comment: @JacobH I've tried dateadd a few times and I then get 0 results.  Can you provide a little more info please?

Comment: Please **STOP** using top 100 percent - it does nothing useful and only serves to mislead anyone reading the code.

Comment: @SMor - OK... I removed it, but the real issue still remains.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect. What month do you compare 2018/01 to? Your logic attempts to join on 2018/0 - which does not exist.

Comment: @SMor  2018/01 should compare to 2017/12.  Yes I understand it does not exist, which is why I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mostly down to you simply not using date values as dates.

The date logic you need is to find the difference in months between an arbitrary date and the `invoicedate`, then add that difference in months to the same arbitrary date to get the first day of that month.  You can then add or subtract from this difference to find months before or after.

You can see this working by playing around with the following:

```
select getdate() as RightNow
      ,dateadd(day,  datediff(day  , 0, getdate())  , 0) as DayStart
      ,dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0) as PreviousMonthStart
      ,dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, getdate())  , 0) as MonthStart
      ,dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, getdate())+1, 0) as NextMonthStart
```

The following should not only work for you, but run in less time due to the lack of functions in your `where` clauses:

```
with _t1 as
(
    select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Invoicedate),0) as InvoiceMonth
        ,sum([TaxableSalesAmt]
            +[NonTaxableSalesAmt]
            +[FreightAmt]
            +[SalesTaxAmt]
            ) as Revenue
    from [InvoiceHistory]
    where invoicedate >= '20150101'
    group by dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Invoicedate),0)
)
,_t2 as
(
    select dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Invoicedate),0) as InvoiceMonth
        ,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Invoicedate)-1,0) as PreviousInvoiceMonth
        ,sum([TaxableSalesAmt]
            +[NonTaxableSalesAmt]
            +[FreightAmt]
            +[SalesTaxAmt]
            ) as Revenue
    from [MAS_RDP].[dbo].[AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader]
    where invoicedate >= '20150101'
    group by dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Invoicedate),0)
            ,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,Invoicedate)-1,0)
)
select _t1.InvoiceMonth
    ,_t1.Revenue
    ,_t2.PreviousInvoiceMonth
    ,_t2.Revenue
    ,_t2.Revenue-_t1.Revenue as GrowthActual
    ,(_t2.Revenue - _t1.Revenue)/_t2.Revenue*100 as GrowthPercent
from _t1
    inner join _t2
        on _t1.InvoiceMonth = _t2.PreviousInvoiceMonth
order by _t1.InvoiceMonth
```

Comment: I had to make a couple changes (group by on 2nd query) and updating the final select statement, but you got me to where I needed.  Much appreciated!